# Getting $h_x, h_y, h_z$ Components of Hamiltonian after Gauge Transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian-formalism, gauge, berry-pancharatnam-phase

In Fruchart et al.'s *[An Introduction to Topological Insulators](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.0255.pdf)*, the Bloch Hamiltonian for a two-band insulator is given in the general form $ H(k)= $

> \begin{bmatrix}
>  h_0+h_z & h_x-i h_y  \\
> h_x + i h_y & h_0 - h_z   \end{bmatrix}

which can be rewritten on the basis of Pauli matrices plus the identity matrix $\sigma_0 = 1$
as:

> $$ H(k)=h_0 (k) + \vec{h}(k)\cdot\vec{\sigma} $$

Now, the Haldane model's tight-binding Hamiltonian is given as:

> $$ H
>   =
>   t \sum_{\langle i,j \rangle} | i \rangle \langle j |
>   + t_{2} \sum_{\langle\langle i,j \rangle\rangle} | i \rangle \langle j |
>   + M \left[\sum_{i \in \mathcal{A}} | i \rangle \langle i |
>   -  \sum_{j \in \mathcal{A}} | j \rangle \langle j | \right ]
> $$

The Fourier transform of the Hamiltonian above with Aharonov–Bohm phases leads to a 2x2 Bloch Hamiltonian in the (A, B) sublattices basis:

> \begin{split}
> h_{0} &= 2 t_{2} \cos{\phi} \sum_{i=1}^{3} \cos(k\cdot b_{i}),
> \\
> h_{x} &= t \left[ 1 + \cos(k \cdot b_{1} ) + \cos(k \cdot b_{2} ) \right ],
> \\
> h_{y} &= t \left[\sin(k \cdot b_{1} ) - \sin(k \cdot b_{2} ) \right ],
> \\
> h_{z} &= M - 2 t_{2} \sin{\phi} \sum_{i=1}^{3} \sin(k \cdot b_{i}).
> \end{split}

My question is: how do I change the gauge of the Hamiltonian and get new expressions for $h_x, h_y, h_z$? Specifically, I want to apply the gauge transformation $g_2(k) = $

> \begin{bmatrix}
>  1 & 0  \\
> 0 & \exp{i(k(b_1+b_2))^2}   \end{bmatrix} 
>   where $b_i$ are lattice vectors.

Using references online, such as some posts on here and [this website](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Gauge_invariance#Quantum_Hamiltonian_in_a_magnetic_field_and_gauge_invariance), the standard protocol seems to involve finding a Unitary matrix $U$ and verifying the identity $U \hat{H} U^\dagger = \hat{H}$. However, it is not clear to me how I could apply the above gauge into the Hamiltonian to get new expressions for $h_x, h_y, h_z$. In the event my question is ill-posed, I would appreciate clarification on what's wrong with my reasoning, and I hope you read the following motivation behind my question with the hope of clarifying the problem from which it stemmed.

---

The motivation for my question comes from this paper by Dobardzic et al.: [*Effective description of Chern insulators*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.4000.pdf). My end goal is to visualize the Berry curvature of the Haldane model over the Brillouin zone, but in a different gauge. Currently, I compute the Berry curvature over a discretized grid by evaluating the equivalent Berry connection using the following idea:

> I approximate the infinitesimal quantity $d \lambda_{\mu}$ by small,
>   finite $\Delta \lambda_{\mu}$:
>
> $$  \begin{split}   \int_{\mathcal{M}}\mathcal{F} &=
>  \iint_{\mathcal{M}}\frac{1}{2} F^{\mu\nu} d\lambda^{\mu} \wedge
>  d\lambda^{\nu},   \\   &=\int\limits_{\partial{\mathcal{M}}}
>  \mathcal{A}^{\mu} d \lambda_{\mu},\\   &\approx \mathcal{A}^{\mu}
> \Delta \lambda_{\mu},\\   \end{split} $$

Without any consideration of gauges, I replicate the up-right figure in their results (copied below) by using the $h_x, h_y, h_z$ specified above.

[image]

From the paper, this apparently corresponds to a gauge transformation using $g_1(k) = $

> \begin{bmatrix}
>  1 & 0  \\
> 0 & \exp{i(kb_2)}   \end{bmatrix}

However, I now want to replicate the down-right figure by applying $g_2$, and my guess is that I can use the same code I did (i.e. approximating $\mathcal{A}^{\mu}
\Delta \lambda_{\mu}$ over a rectangle in the Brillouin zone) but with a gauge-transformed Hamiltonian. 
I can follow theoretical proofs of gauge dependance/invariance under certain transformations on Berry connection $A$ and Berry curvature $F$ (such as in [this article](http://www.physics.iisc.ernet.in/~aveek_bid/Vanderbilt_ch-3.pdf)), however, my code relies on the Hamiltonian components $h_x, h_y, h_z$ and so it is not clear to me how I can go about replicating the figure I need. If it isn't the Hamiltonian that changes under this gauge transformation, it is probably $A$, and I would still like insight on how to think about this too.

I apologize this question is too long, but I would appreciate any pointers/references on how I could solve my problem! Please let me know if any crucial information is missing. Thanks!